# Change height of AppBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing a Flutter app. In this app I have used TabBarController in app bar. I am not using icons and title for AppBar so height is showing me more than expectation. I need help to do this with desired size. I am using following code:

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    new Tab(text: 'page1.',),
    new Tab(text: 'page2.'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        bottom: new TabBar(
          indicatorSize:TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
          labelStyle: styleTabText,

        ),
      ),
      body:  new TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          return new Center(
              child: new Text(
                  tab.text
              )
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also for reference I am adding screenshot of app. 
[image]

Comment: Are you creating this scaffold inside the body of another scaffold maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [PreferredSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) to adjust the TabBar's height:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TabBar _tabBar = new TabBar(
      indicatorSize:TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      controller: _tabController,
      tabs: myTabs,
      labelStyle: styleTabText,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(_tabBar.preferredSize.height - 50),
          child: _tabBar,
        ),
      ),

      // (...)

    );
  }
```

Comment: I am getting error 
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/material/tabs.dart': Failed assertion: line 65 pos 15: '!(text != null && null != child)': is not true.

Comment: @CodeHunter this is related to the tabs definition, check the `myTabs` declaration (it must have a text or child property).

Answer (score 4):

Use `toolbarHeight`:

```dart
AppBar(
  toolbarHeight: 44, 
  // ...
)
```

Comment: This doesn't reduce height of the Tab. I want to have fix height of AppBar with small tab bar.

Comment: @Yash This does reduce the height of the `AppBar`. The question isn't asking for `Tab` stuff. If you have a particular question feel free to ask by clicking "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `toolbarHeight` property in your AppBar

**Example :**

```
AppBar(
   title: Text('Flutter is great'),
   toolbarHeight: 100,
  ),
```

**Output**:

[image]